# Create TToolbutton runtime

Tags: delphi, toolbar

I have a problem with creating `TToolbuttons` at runtime and how they appear in my `TToolbar`.

Basically I got a toolbar with some buttons in it already. I can create  buttons at runtime
and set the parent to the toolbar. But they are always shown as the first buttons in my toolbar.

How can I make them appear at the end of my toolbar? Or any position I want them to be.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a generic procedure that takes a toolbar, and adds a button to it, with a specified caption:

```
procedure AddButtonToToolbar(var bar: TToolBar; caption: string);
var
  newbtn: TToolButton;
  lastbtnidx: integer;
begin
  newbtn := TToolButton.Create(bar);
  newbtn.Caption := caption;
  lastbtnidx := bar.ButtonCount - 1;
  if lastbtnidx > -1 then
    newbtn.Left := bar.Buttons[lastbtnidx].Left + bar.Buttons[lastbtnidx].Width
  else
    newbtn.Left := 0;
  newbtn.Parent := bar;
end;
```

And here is example usage of that procedure:

```
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ToolBar1.ShowCaptions := True;  //by default, this is False
  AddButtonToToolbar(ToolBar1,IntToStr(ToolBar1.ButtonCount));
end;
```

Your question does also ask how to add a button to an **arbitrary** place on the TToolbar.  This code is similar to before, but it also allows you to specify which index you want the new button to appear **after**.

```
procedure AddButtonToToolbar(var bar: TToolBar; caption: string;
  addafteridx: integer = -1);
var
  newbtn: TToolButton;
  prevBtnIdx: integer;
begin
  newbtn := TToolButton.Create(bar);
  newbtn.Caption := caption;

  //if they asked us to add it after a specific location, then do so
  //otherwise, just add it to the end (after the last existing button)
  if addafteridx = -1 then begin
    prevBtnIdx := bar.ButtonCount - 1;
  end
  else begin
    if bar.ButtonCount <= addafteridx then begin
      //if the index they want to be *after* does not exist,
      //just add to the end
      prevBtnIdx := bar.ButtonCount - 1;
    end
    else begin
      prevBtnIdx := addafteridx;
    end;
  end;

  if prevBtnIdx > -1 then
    newbtn.Left := bar.Buttons[prevBtnIdx].Left + bar.Buttons[prevBtnIdx].Width
  else
    newbtn.Left := 0;

  newbtn.Parent := bar;
end;
```

And here is example usage for this revised version:

```
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //by default, "ShowCaptions" is false
  ToolBar1.ShowCaptions := True;

  //in this example, always add our new button immediately after the 0th button
  AddButtonToToolbar(ToolBar1,IntToStr(ToolBar1.ButtonCount),0);
end;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Aargh....we're doing the same thing except that I assign the Parent before the Left value. And it was screwing up the layout. Your's is reverse and now I'm happy. Thanks !

Comment: @Roderick: glad it helped!  I revised the answer to include a way to add to an arbitrary point on the TToolbar, too.

Comment: @JosephStyons: Thanks for this. I was looking to add TToolButtons at runtime, and my first attempt didn't work properly. Rather than wasting time, I decided to do a quick search here, and found your post. Saved me some time. :) +1

Comment: @JosephStyons: Same story as Ken. I'm glad this showed up at the top of a Google search for "add a button to a ttoolbar".  This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `left` property of the [`TToolButton`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ComCtrls.TToolButton) component

check this sample

```
//adding buttons to the end  of the ToolBar.
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 Toolbutton : TToolButton;
begin
   Toolbutton :=TToolButton.Create(ToolBar1);
   Toolbutton.Parent  := ToolBar1;
   Toolbutton.Caption := IntToStr(ToolBar1.ButtonCount);
   Toolbutton.Left    := ToolBar1.Buttons[ToolBar1.ButtonCount-1].Left + ToolBar1.ButtonWidth;
end;
```

Comment: what is `ToolBar1.Buttons[-1]` ?

Comment: This is buggy. ToolButton OnClick runs other ToolButton's OnClick.

Answer (score 0):

If it works like the Scroll Panel then you can set the .left property to be 1 more than a button to place it to the left of that button.  Or set the .left property to be 1 less than the button to place it to the right of that button.