# Delphi - Order of controls in a panel

Tags: delphi

I have a panel and in realtime I add one or more buttons to this panel:

[image]

I can move the buttons panel by changing their order. After moving them I need to know who is in what position.

I'm trying:

```
for i := Pred(panel.ControlCount) downto 0 do
begin
  vButtonName := panel.Controls[i].name;
end;
```

But panel.Controls[i].name does not show the expected order of the components if their were moved. It's my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use the property "left" to find the sequence. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093595/create-ttoolbutton-runtime) is some code to create buttons in the wanted sequence and the property left determines the position

Comment: Thank you, but but the problem is that the panel.Controls[i].name does not show the expected order of the components if their were moved.

Comment: @giaco You cannot simply move through your controls, they are not in your order by the index. You have to create a new list and sort the items by their property "left". Please try to understand the code in the link I provided in my answer

Comment: Your answer inspired me and so I did: I used the property left to identify the button position. I threw in an array and then ordered. Thank you!

Comment: Please mark as answer if it works